# Casting of arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, casting

In C# I am working with large arrays of value types. I want to be able to cast arrays of compatible value types, for example:

```
struct Color
{
    public byte R, G, B, A;
}

Color[] bitmap1 = ...;
uint[] bitmap2 = MagicCast(bitmap1);
```

I want bitmap2 to share memory with bitmap1 (they have the same bit representations). I don't want to make a copy.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: No, you can't. It's UB even in C (where you can play free with memory and casts).

Comment: @Adriano It's only UB if you dereference the casted array. If the array is cast back to Color* before being dereferenced it's valid.

Comment: only way i can think of is with unsafe, i did something similar a long time a go... let me check my old stuff

Comment: @kaalus true but pretty useless ;)

Comment: Note internally `Color` is represented by a `readonly long value;`

Comment: @ja72 Note that the definition of `Color` is present in the question, containing 4 byte fields. If the question is about the `System.Drawing.Color` type, answers will be different, possibly that it's not possible.

Comment: I think that `unsafe` is the way to go here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accheive this by using Structlayouts to overlay both arrays.
While many answers here wrote how to make the color-struct have a uint aswell, this is about the "array" conversion:

**This is evil.**

```
public static class ColorExtension
{
    public static uint[] GetUInts(this Color[] colors)
    {
        if(colors == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("colors");
        Evil e = new Evil { Colors = colors};
        return e.UInts;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    struct Evil
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public Color[] Colors;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public uint[] UInts;
    }
}
```

This basically has two Arrays refering the same memory Location.

So If you want to get the array of uints from the array of colors you do it like this:

```
Color[] colors =  ...

uint[] uints = colors.GetUInts();
```

---

As mentioned in the comments, you might need to declare the colorstruct explicitly aswell, or the runtime may fumble arround with the order leading to some "strange" uint values...

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] // Or explicit, but i bellieve Sequential is enough.
struct Color
{
      public byte R;

      public byte G;

      public byte B;

      public byte A;
}
```

Dont try to debug it though...
[image: One of the reasons why this is evil:]

Comment: How would this work without also doing it to the Color struct as well?  Without the explicit layout, you can't know how the runtime is going to store your Color struct, and thus the results could be unpredictable, no?

Comment: +1 nice catch and it's only answer (so far) that give OP the ability to get uint[] instead of uint*!

Comment: I'm so going to test this later. The initial structlayout was obvious, but I never thought of doing it another layer up. Kudos.

Comment: I thought this wasn't allowed when the fields being overlaid was object references, but darned if it didn't work. Nice! (and yes, evil, EVIL!)

Comment: The debugger doesn't much like this approach. It has much trouble understanding what is going on when attempting to evaluate.

Comment: Same with LINQPad, ask it to dump the array of units and out comes colors :)

Comment: I am not sure why people call it evil. The color is made out of bytes, so effectively an array of colors is an array of bytes, 4 times larger. I can treat a single color as 4 bytes easily enough, and it's very useful at times, not sure why doing the same to the entire array should be so difficult and evil. I think the language should have a facility for that. Any struct that has no private members and all members are PODs should be castable to any other struct which meets the same conditions - and this should extend to arrays as long as sizes match.

Comment: I called it like this since the debugger doesnt like it ant it looks way different than the things you usually do in c#.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this, but with the struct as posted, it may work just by chance.

You should definitely add some attributes to your struct in order to ensure there's no padding added.

Anyway, here's a [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program that demonstrates:

```
unsafe void Main()
{
    Color[] c = new Color[2]
    {
        new Color { R = 255, G = 0, B = 0, A = 0 },
        new Color { R = 0, G = 255, B = 0, A = 0 }
    };
    c.Dump();


    fixed (byte* p = &c[0].R)
    {
        uint* i = (uint*)p;
        *i = 0x11223344;
        *(i + 1) = 0x55667788;
    };
    c.Dump();
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
struct Color
{
    public byte R, G, B, A;
}
```

This will output the two colors, twice, where the second time it has been modified.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you essentially trying to treat your Color object as a C union?

Do this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct Color
{
   [FieldOffset(0)]
   byte R;
   [FieldOffset(1)]
   byte G;
   [FieldOffset(2)]
   byte B;
   [FieldOffset(3)]
   byte A;

   [FieldOffset(0)]
   uint Value;
}
```

To get your IEnumerable from a Color[] without making a copy, just do:

```
var converted = colorArray.Select( c => c.Value );
```

Shouldn't make any copies, I wouldn't think, as it should just be a projection of the values into an array.

You could probably even go a step farther and add an explicit and implicit cast operator for your new type.

```
struct Color
{
   //...As before...

   public static implicit operator uint(Color input)
   {
      return input.Value;
   }

   public static explicit operator uint(Color input)
   {
      return input.Value;
   }
}
```

Then you'd be able to do something like the following:

```
Color a = new Color();
uint b = a;        //Completely valid, with the implicit cast.
uint c = (uint)a;  //Also valid, but the implicit cast makes it unnecessary.
```

This does not cover array casting, however.

Comment: Well, ToArray() creates a new array which could be seen as a copy of some sort ^^

Comment: He wants to cast to uint[], which is a pointer. Calling ToArray() creates that pointer. It's identical to a cast.  ANY linq method is going to result in additional pointers, no matter what.  Simply calling the select without ToArray() doesn't save anything,  and just results in an IEnumerable<uint> instead of uint[] (which is, of course, also an IEnumerable<uint>.

Comment: I see the use of Clone here: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/emit/methodbuilder.cs which feels like a copy to me :) But I think we argue about what the OP meant with copy. Depends on him/her.

Comment: Yuck. That's what I get for assuming it was a simple projection.  In any case, I've added more to the answer that might work better for OP's case.

Comment: The rub is, if the OP needs that uint[] to pass to some external function (seems likely), then chances are he's stuck making a copy, unless he wants to write an unsafe method to write an array using pointers to the original uints.

Answer (score 0):

this should do what you want, you change one, it change both reference

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    struct Color
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public uint value;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public byte R;
        [FieldOffset(1)]
        public byte G;
        [FieldOffset(2)]
        public byte B;
        [FieldOffset(3)]
        public byte A;

        static public implicit operator uint(Color c)
        {
            return c.value;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Color[] colors = new Color[] { new Color { R = 255 }, new Color { B = 255 } };
            Console.WriteLine(colors[0]);
            Console.WriteLine(colors[1]);
            fixed (Color* thisPtr = &colors[0])
            {
                ((uint*)thisPtr)[0] = 2;
                ((uint*)thisPtr)[1] = 4;
                Console.WriteLine(colors[0]);
                Console.WriteLine(colors[1]);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
unit[] bitmap2 = bitmap1.Select((c)=>c.ToUint32()).ToArray();
```

You might have to create an extension method to convert `Color` to `uint`

```
public static uint ToUint32(this Color color) { ... }
```

Comment: It doesn't work (**no conversion between his struct and uint**). Even if we have a conversion it makes a copy, we may assume OP knows how to do it but he's asking to avoid that.

Comment: By definition values times are going to make a copy.

Comment: No, if there was (just imagine, there is not) a way to access Color* as it was UInt32* then there will be no copy. That's what OP is asking for.

Comment: Internally a `Color` is an `long` and not an `uint`. So you could get a pointer to the private `Color.value` field

Answer (score -1):

It seems you want to have a different representation of the same thing. The color in 4 bytes or as one uint. This is done with unions in C. There is no native union construct in C# but functionality can be reproduced with StructLayout and FieldOffset attributes. Something like this:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct Color
{
  [FieldOffset(0)]
  public byte R;

  [FieldOffset(1)]
  public byte G;

  [FieldOffset(2)]
  public byte B;

  [FieldOffset(3)]
  public byte A;

  [FieldOffset(0)]
  public uint value;
}
```

You can then use your Color array bitmap1 to select what you need, e.g.:

```
var allRedBytes = bitmap1.Select(c => c.R);
var allUInts = bitmap1.Select(c => c.value);
```

As long as you dont call .ToArray or .ToList on that LINQ queries you dont produce a new copy of the bitmap array. These queries only describe how to walk through an array when you use the query in a foreach loop for example.

Comment: FieldOffset can simulate a union but this code will make a copy (because it's a value type).

Comment: I don't know how C# handles that stuff but do you have any evidence for your statement? And why I am the only one getting down vote although most have the same answer ^^ j/k

Comment: bitmap1.Select(c => c.R) will create an enumeration of source values. You can't modify them (because they're value types then you get a copy). Just try.Moreover It's IEnumerable<uint> and not uint[] as required (and if you add ToArray() you'll create a fresh new copy completely unrelated to original one.

Comment: "I want bitmap2 to share memory with bitmap1 [...] I don't want to make a copy" quote by OP. So an enumeration is a valid option. I assumed though that the casting the OP is asking for is not his main goal.

Comment: But they're both declared as arrays. If you have to consume that data (unless performance are an issue and/or type is fixed because it must be consumed by another unchangeable function) it's not such problem but if you have to modify them then they (enumeration) doesn't work.

Comment: You would of course modify the original bitmap1 array in this case. My LINQs where just an example of what could be done as we dont know what OP wants to do :)